# With Dagger 2, is it possible to inject on a same class from different subcomponents or from different components?

Tags: android, dagger-2

It seems to be impossible but I can't find it written explicitly. Is there a clear reason for that ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for it? 
You can create separate component that depends on a few subcomponents .

Comment: I have a A project which depends on a B project. A project constructs parameters for services of the B project (these services can be used by different activities). I have put these parameters in a module in the A project and the service construction in a module in the B project. As these 2 modules are related, I wondered if I could use subcomponents to add a relation between them. It is possible but what if I had to reproduce this structure, will I be able to use both subcomponents in a same activity (in project B) ?

Comment: Subcomponents then seems more suited for a "feature" perspective (module composed of implementations of the different services used) than a "type" perspective (module composed by different types of service) like the one I use for these modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. A component can either inject everything at once or the compilation will fail with a *cannot be provided* error, listing what it's missing.

After all you can't partially call a constructor (if using constructor injection) and also partially injecting fields would be rather indeterministic about which objects were injected when, how, or with which scope. If both components could supply a dependency, which should provide it? Do you create and inject the object twice? What if another object depends on it in the other component? It would create more confusion than any good it could do and provide a source for a lot of errors and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `component` can be used to inject inside a given class. You can have several `subcomponent`s dependencies installed on it though.